# Comparing/ Matching elements of 2 vectors by MATLAB

Tags: match, element

I would like to compare/match elements of 2 vector data, **the goal is to select the elements which element-wise from the 2 vectors are different not greater than 3**. Then output are the 2 new vector with have the same length and its elements are arranged in order. The size of the 2 vectors (before processed) is arbitrary.

Ex. A = [11 38 49 84 96 117 157 176 200];
    B = [10 28 37 48 84 157 175 200];

Compare by element which abs(A(i) - B(j)) <= 3
Then the output should be 
    A_new = [11 38 49 84 157 176 200]
    B_new = [10 37 48 84 157 175 200]
Can anyone guide me how to write MATLAB code for this problem? I used 2 nested loop but got stuck with empty set fault.
Thank you.